# SQL hourly log , show all matching rows that have a value below threshold for n hours

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a simple SQL log table (named market_history in SQLite) for US markets it looks something like this:

**Sample table (market_history)**

```
id  datetime        market    percent 
1   9/5/2014 7:50   ARIZONA      50.0 
2   9/5/2014 7:50   ATLANTA      97.4 
3   9/5/2014 7:50   AUSTIN       78.8 
4   9/5/2014 7:50   BOSTON       90.9 
6   9/5/2014 7:50   CHARLOTTE    100.0 
7   9/5/2014 7:50   CHICAGO      90.3
```

This table is an hourly snapshot of network capacity in various systems in each market. What I would like to do is set up an alert system that if any one particular market is below a threshold percent (say 50) for more than 2 consecutive hours (each row is recorded every hour), it triggers an alert email.. So the query should show me a a unique list of Market names where the percents is < 50.0 for more than the last 2 consecutive entries

Here's the SQL I'm trying, but it's not working:

**Sample SQL (not working):**

```
SELECT 
mh.datetime, mh.market, mh.percent
 FROM  markets_history mh
WHERE
 (SELECT mh1.precent FROM markets_history mh1 WHERE  mh1.datetime BETWEEN "2015-03-23 00:00:00" AND "2015-03-23 00:59:59" AND mh.market=mh1.market ) < 50 AND (SELECT mh2.precent FROM markets_history mh2 WHERE  mh2.datetime BETWEEN "2015-03-23 01:00:00" AND "2015-03-23 01:59:59" AND mh.market=mh2.market ) < 50
ORDER by mh.datetime
```

I know I'm missing something.. any sugggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the time windows are fixed and reliable, just make sure the largest one isn't more than the threshold. It wouldn't really matter how far back you look either if you needed to extend this to more than two.

```
select market
from markets_history mh
where mh.datetime between <last_two_hours> and <now>
group by mh.market
having max(percent) < 50.0
    -- and count(*) = 2 /* if you need to be sure of two ... */
```

Comment: This almost works, but it needs to account for consecutive values below the threshold,  not just any two values that are below the threshold. I suppose I could play around with the between t1 and t2 and just keep that to two

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that should work in SQLite.  Find the last good id (if any) in each market.  Then count the number of rows larger than than id.

```
select lastgood.market,
       sum(case when lastgood.market is null then 1
                when lastgood.id < mh.id then 1
                else 0
           end) as NumInRow
from market_history mh left join
     (select market, max(id) as maxid
      from market_history mh
      where percent < 50.0
      group by market
     ) as lastgood
     on lastgood.market = mh.market and lastgood.id < mh.id;
```

This query is a little bit complicated because it needs to take into account the possibility of there not being any good id.  If that is the case, then all rows for the market count.